# Regex find optional entries in Java

Tags: java, regex, optional-parameters

I'm currently working on some stuff with regex and struggel alot with regex latetly.

I wanted to build some script engine, for that I need to load some presets:

example:

```
create <Type> [after;before;at;between(2);<Integer>, <DateTime>, <Date>, <Time>, <String>] : Creator
edit <Type> [after;before;at;between(2);<Integer>, <DateTime>, <Date>, <Time>, <String>]
run [<File>, <Command>]
```

So I want to make sure I can read `<Type> [after;before;at;between(2);<Integer>, <DateTime>, <Date>, <Time>, <String>]` and `[<File>, <Command>]`.

For the understanding:

`NAME <IMPORTANT_PARAMETER> [TEXT_PARAMETER(AMOUNT_OF_OPTIONAL_PAREMETER);<OPTIONAL_PARAMETER(S)>]`.

In this example I used 'command names' as `IMPORTANT_PARAMETER`.

For the first rule I made this regex: `\<(\w+)\>(?:\s+\[(?:(.*;))(.*)\])?(?:\s+\:\s+(\w+))?` and it kinda works within my code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\<(\\w+)\\>(?:\\s+\\[(?:(.*;))(.*)\\])?(?:\\s+\\:\\s+(\\w+))?");
Matcher m = p.matcher(parameters);
if(m.matches()){
    Command command2 = new Command(command);
    command2.addParameter(new Parameter(m.group(1)));

    String text = m.group(2);
    String[] texts = null;
    if(text != null){
        texts = text.split(";");
        command2.addTexts(Arrays.asList(texts));
    }
    String type = m.group(3);
    String[] types = null;
    if(type != null){
        types = type.split(", ");
        for (String string : types) {
            Pattern pTypes = Pattern.compile("\\<(?:(\\w+))\\>");
            Matcher mTypes = pTypes.matcher(string);
            if(mTypes.matches()){
                command2.addParameter(new Parameter(mTypes.group(1), true));
            }
        }
    }
    String className = m.group(4);
    if(className != null){
        command2.addClassName(className);
    }
    commandslist.add(command2);
}
```

I tried to use `\[\<(\w+)\>(?:,\s+\<(\w+)\>)+\]` but it only worked for two entries -> example `run [<File>, <Command>]`. It would be better having a "list" of those optional elements `[<File>, <Command>]`. So in the end I want to have `m.group(1) = File; m.group(2) = Command; m.group(3) = blablabla;` and so on.

I hope I could show you my problem good enough, hit me with questions if there is anything more to explain.

Here is a link to the `regexr`: [REGEXR](http://regexr.com/3fkmq) or `regex101`: [REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/0HRo2O/1)

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: The problem is that at least Java's regex engine can't provide more than one value per capturing group, i.e. you'd either have to provide several groups like `\[(g1)(g2)?(g3)?(g4)?...\]` or use multiple expressions to match the parameters (e.g. first extract the parameters from the input then apply a second expression along with `Matcher.find()` to extract them).

Comment: `<` and `>` are not special in Java regexes, no need to prepend them with backslashes

Answer (score 0):

[My suggestion](http://ideone.com/tHjQZL) is to match the stuff between the words you are after:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    final String STR1 = "run [<File>, <Command1>, <Command2>, <Command3>]";
    final String STR2 = "run [<File>, <Command1>, <Command2>, <Command3>, <Command4>]";

    System.out.println(parse(STR1));
    System.out.println(parse(STR2));
}

private static List parse(String str) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:\\G,\\s+|^run\\s+\\[(?:<\\w+>,\\s+)+?)<(\\w+)>");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    while (m.find()) {
        list.add(m.group(1));
    }

    return list;
}
```

which results in the output:

```
[Command1, Command2, Command3]
[Command1, Command2, Command3, Command4]
```